# User input from GUI in Python 3.5

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-3.5

So, I'm pretty new to Python, but I am having trouble handling the variables once they are placed in a class.

The following code works fine when there is no surrounding class, but once I add it I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'someName' is not defined
```

Which occurs on the 3rd line

```
text = "You have entered " + someName.get()
```

Here's the code:

```
class GUI:
    def changeLabel():
        text = "You have entered " + someName.get()
        labelText.set(text)
        someName.delete(0, END)
        someName.insert(0, "You've clicked!")
        return

    app = Tk()
    app.title("GUI Test")
    app.geometry('450x300')

    labelText = StringVar()
    labelText.set("Click when ready")
    label1 = Label(app, textvariable=labelText, height=4)
    label1.pack()

    userInput = StringVar(None)
    someName = Entry(app, textvariable=userInput)
    someName.pack()

    button1 = Button(app, text="Click Here", width=20,command=changeLabel)
    button1.pack(side='bottom',padx=15,pady=15)

    app.mainloop()

GUI #calling the class to run
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `GUI #calling the class to run` Nope. That's not how you call it. Please check python class tutorials first.

Comment: There are a lot of issues here. You should probably reread the `TKinter` tutorial.

Comment: Also, you should describe in your question what you expect your code to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GUI` class is not well-formed. You shouldn't just dump code into a class, it should be in a method (a function that belongs to a class). For stuff like this, the usual way to do it is to put it in the `__init__` method, which gets called automatically when you create an instance of the class by calling it.

Methods can have their own local variables, and they can also access the attributes of the instance, using the `self.attribute_name` syntax. Your `NameError: name 'someName' is not defined` error message is because Python thinks that `someName` is a local variable of `changeLabel`, it doesn't realise that it's supposed to be your `Entry` widget.

Anyway, I've repaired your code so that it runs; presumably it does what you intended. Note that the methods have `self` as their 1st argument. Please read some Python docs / tutorials about classes for further info.

```
from Tkinter import *

class GUI(object):
    def changeLabel(self):
        text = "You have entered " + self.someName.get()
        self.labelText.set(text)
        self.someName.delete(0, END)
        self.someName.insert(0, "You've clicked!")            

    def __init__(self):
        app = Tk()
        app.title("GUI Test")
        app.geometry('450x300')

        self.labelText = StringVar()
        self.labelText.set("Click when ready")
        label1 = Label(app, textvariable=self.labelText, height=4)
        label1.pack()

        userInput = StringVar(None)
        self.someName = Entry(app, textvariable=userInput)
        self.someName.pack()

        button1 = Button(app, text="Click Here", width=20,command=self.changeLabel)
        button1.pack(side='bottom',padx=15,pady=15)

        app.mainloop()

GUI() #calling the class to run
```

This code works on Python 2; you'll need to change the `import` statement on Python 3 to `from tkinter import *`. Actually, it's not recommended to use `import *`, since it pollutes your namespace with all the imported names. It's better to do something like

```
import tkinter as tk
```

and then write your Tkinter references like

```
app = tk.Tk()
```

and

```
label1 = tk.Label(app, textvariable=self.labelText, height=4)
```

Etc

Comment: Thank you. I am aware it is no where near decent Python code, and tutorials I had looked into did not go into classes and method set up as you have above. I suppose I will have to dig through some good tutorials as quick as I can.

Comment: @coelicasi: No problem. The `import *` pattern is pretty common in example code (even the official docs / tutorials) since it makes the code less verbose, but unfortunately it gives people the idea that it's a good practice. You _can_ do simple GUI stuff without organizing your code into a class, but it soon gets messy when you try to build a complex GUI. As well as looking at tutorials there's lots of great example code right here on SO, although sometimes even the experts will use the `import *` pattern to keep things simple.

Answer (score 0):

You have a some errors in your code, and aren't using classes in the way that you should be. I've modified your code and commented the new lines so you understand what's happening. I've added `self` references to all the text variables so they can be accessed properly.

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI:
        #set these so that they are able to be used by the whole class
        labelText = ""
        userInput = "" 

        #you should have an init method for your classes and do all the setup here
        def __init__(self,master):   
                self.labelText = StringVar()
                self.userInput = StringVar()

                #you should pack things into a frame
                frame = Frame(master)     
                frame.pack()

                self.labelText.set("Click when ready")
                label1 = Label(frame, textvariable=self.labelText, height=4)
                label1.pack()

                someName = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.userInput)
                someName.pack()

                button1 = Button(frame, text="Click Here", width=20,command=self.changeLabel)
                button1.pack(side='bottom',padx=15,pady=15)

        def changeLabel(self):
                text = "You have entered " + self.userInput.get()
                self.labelText.set(text)
                self.userInput.set("You've clicked!")
                return

#create the app before you call the GUI.
app = Tk()
app.title("GUI Test")
app.geometry('450x300')

# when you create the class, you need to assign it to a variable
applet = GUI(app) #calling the class to run
app.mainloop()
```